# C言語でPOSIX規定関数のlfind関数で配列要素にマッチした文字列の参照方法

Tags: c, posix

C言語で，[POSIXに規定されているlfind関数](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/lfind.html)を使って，配列内の文字列の検索を試しています。

マッチはできるのですが，肝心のマッチした文字列を参照できなくて困っています。

検証環境は以下のとおりです。

- Ubuntu 16.04
- gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

サンプルコードを以下に示します。配列要素内の，"break"にマッチします。

```
/// \file find_array.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <search.h>

int main(void) {
    char *tab[] = {"auto", "break"};
    size_t nel = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
    // char *target = "break";
    char *entry = lfind(&(void *){"break"}, tab, &nel, sizeof(tab[0]), (int (*)(const void *, const void*))strcmp);

    if (entry) {
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", (void *)&tab[1], tab[1] );
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", entry, entry);
    } else {
        puts("NOT FOUND");
    }

    // 数値の場合
    // int tab[] = {1, 2, 3};
    // size_t nel = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
    // void *entry = lfind(&(int){2}, tab, &nel, sizeof(tab[0]), (int (*)(const void *, const void*))strcmp);
    // アクセスは間接参照を使う
    // printf("found: %d\n", *(int *)entry);

    return 0;
}
```

このfind_array.cをコンパイルして実行すると，以下のような出力が得られます。

```
found: 0x7ffddffe2748:break
found: 0x7ffddffe2748:�@
```

lfindはマッチした場合に，マッチした要素のアドレスを返却しており，実際，上記の結果の通り元の配列の該当要素と同じアドレスでした。

そのまま文字列も参照できるかと思ったのですが，ダメでした (*&やキャストなどでいろいろ`entry`変数へのアクセスのしかたを試しても結局ダメ)。何か，根本的なところの理解が足りていないような気がしています。

幸い，非NULLのポインターを取得できておりマッチしているかどうかはわかるので，検索に使ったキーを使えば，間接的にマッチした文字列は参照できます。

しかし，できることならば，マッチした結果 (entry変数) からマッチした値を参照したいのです。何かアクセスのしかたに工夫が必要なのでしょうか？どうかご教授お願いします。

なお，サンプルコードの下の方に掲載している通り，配列が数値の場合は間接参照演算子*で参照することで，マッチした値にアクセスできました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

成功している`int`型の配列を検索している例をよく考えてみてください。`lfind`の結果を`int *`型、つまり`int`のポインタにキャストしてから、その参照先をアクセスしていますよね?

文字列を扱っているあなたのコードでは`char *`型の配列を検索しています。でしたら、`lfind`の結果は「`char *`のポインタ」、別の言い方をすると`char **`にキャストしなければいけません。

```
int main(void) {
    char *tab[] = {"auto", "break"};
    size_t nel = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
    char **entry = lfind(&(void *){"break"}, tab, &nel, sizeof(tab[0]), (int (*)(const void *, const void*))strcmp);

    if (entry) {
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", (void *)&tab[1], tab[1] );
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", entry, *entry);
    } else {
        puts("NOT FOUND");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

これで1件落着しそうに思うのですが、まだ少し足りません。`lfind`の第5引数である比較関数には「要素型へのポインタ」が渡されます。つまり要素型が`int`なら`int *`、要素型が`char *`なら`char **`を引数にとるような関数を渡さないとなりません。

したがって正しくはこんな感じになります。

```
int cmpare_cstr(char **str1, char **str2) {
    printf("comparing: %s - %s\n", *str1, *str2);
    return strcmp(*str1, *str2);
}

int main(void) {
    char *tab[] = {"auto", "break"};
    size_t nel = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
    char *target = "break";
    char **entry = lfind(&target, tab, &nel, sizeof(tab[0]), (int (*)(const void *, const void*))cmpare_cstr);

    if (entry) {
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", (void *)&tab[1], tab[1] );
        printf("found: %p:%s\n", entry, *entry);
    } else {
        puts("NOT FOUND");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

あなたのコードではポインタの内容の4または8バイトの内容を`strcmp`で比較してしまっています。ポインタそのものを表すバイトの途中に0x00が現れれば、誤った結果を出すでしょうし、逆に0x00がどこにもない領域に配列が置かれていたら、メモリ未割り当ての領域アクセスで異常終了するかもしれません。

- 要素は何型なのか
- 結果は要素型そのものなのか、要素へのポインタなのか
- 比較関数に渡されるのは要素型そのものなのか、要素へのポインタなのか

この辺をきちんと理解して置かないと`lfind`は使えません。特にポインタへのポインタ(C言語の学習でも、中級まで頑張れた人がつまづくポイントですね)が絡んでくると難しく見えますが、基本は「要素型は何型なのか」です。そこら辺に気を使いながらいろいろ試して見られると良いでしょう。

---

もう一度まとめておくと、

検索対象配列の要素型を`T`とした時、

- `lfind`の戻り値型は`T*`
- `lfind`の第一引数の型は`T*`
- `lfind`の第5引数である比較関数の引数型は両方とも`T*`

そして、あなたの文字列検索の場合`T`は(「`T*`は」ではないですよ)、`char *`だと言うことになります。

Comment: 詳細なご回答ありがとうございます！やはり，根本的なところの理解が不十分でした…

この指摘内容が気になりました。
「あなたのコードではポインタの内容の4または8バイトの内容をstrcmpで比較してしまっています。ポインタそのものを表すバイトの途中に0x00が現れれば、誤った結果を出すでしょうし、逆に0x00がどこにもない領域に配列が置かれていたら、メモリ未割り当ての領域アクセスで異常終了するかもしれません。」

Comment: (スタックオーバーフローは不慣れで，コメントは5分しか編集できないとのことで続きをこちらに書きました。)

最初の例の段階で，マッチ自体はできているようにみえましたが，実際はたまたまうまくいっていたと解釈しました。

よろしければ，うまくいかないパターンを一つ示していただけませんか？。

Comment: 何度も恐縮です。C言語で配列の検索はけっこう頻度の高い項目であり，lfindとstrcmpを組み合わせれば，自分で比較関数を書かなくても手短にできる！と思って試していました。

先ほどの，「ポインタの内容の4または8バイトの内容を」の指摘内容からすると，たまたまうまくいっただけで，int型の配列要素の検索に使う場合も問題があるということでしょうか？

Comment: @senooken さん、はい実はその通りです。長くなるので省略しましたが、実はint型の場合にうまくいったのは「たまたま」、char *型の場合にヒットしたところで止まったのも「たまたま」です。興味があるのであれば、別質問としてご質問くだされば詳しく書かせていただきます。

Comment: OOper さん。興味があるので，別質問を立てさせていただきます。明日の夜中頃までには立てさせていただきたいと思いますので，よければまたどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @senooken さん、了解致しました。このサイトは私なんか足元にも及ばないほどC言語に詳しい方々も頻繁に訪れておられるので、うまいタイミングであれば、それらの方に回答をいただけるかもしれません。ご質問を書かれる際には、このスレのリンクを埋め込んで、「関連質問だが、聞きたいことは別」と言うのを明記していただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: OOper さん。こちらに投稿しました。 [C言語のPOSIX定義関数のlfindで配列要素の検索がうまくできているか自信がない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45278/) お手暇なときにでも，よければご解説お願いします。